# Angular momentum conservation during motorbike jump - modelling

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, energy-conservation

I have now found 2 ways of describing this phenomenon and I would like to know which way is correct or better:

When the rear wheel rotates, we can take a look at the angular momentum (around the rotational axis of the rear wheel).

First way: We then take a look at the angular momentum of the rest of the motorbike (frame, person, front wheel) around the rotational axis of the rear wheel and use conservation of angular momentum to explain, why breaking lowers the front wheel.

Second way: We then take a look at the angular momentum of the whole system (frame, person, front wheel AND rear wheel) around the center of mass and use conservation of angular momentum to explain, why breaking lowers the front wheel.

The first way seems to lack an explanation of why an upright standing motorbike driver rotates less quickly than a crouched down one - clearly the rotational axis goes through the center of mass.

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: when you press the brakes there is a torque on the wheels which will violate conservation of angular momentum

Comment: How? If I don't consider heat dissipation or friction with air, then the system is closed? And breaking will reduce angular momentum of the wheel and increase angular momentum of the whole bike?

Comment: For a free body you need to look at net angular momentum about the center of mass, and not the wheel center. Then you see how angular momentum is conserved (when heat/friction/drag is ignored). When braking ang. momenum transfers from the wheel to the chassis.

Comment: @ja72, what about the torque from the friction of the wheels, will not that change the angular momentum?

Comment: I was thinking during flight. While accelerating, momentum isn't conserved.